# Log in / Sign up buttons very close

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

The buttons "Log in" and "Sign up" are very close to each other, there is no margin: [image: Stackoverflow header with log in / sign up buttons]

I think, this used to be different.

Comment: Related: [Change the way log in and sign up buttons (in header) appear in mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377567/change-the-way-log-in-and-sign-up-buttons-in-header-appear-in-mobile).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report! We have a fix for this in place that will go out with the next build.